# the loading of i915 driver

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

The background is that I have a HP ProOne 400 G4(CPU:i3-8100T/GPU:Intel UHD 630) which graphics card doesn't work well with Ubuntu 18.04.

I had carefully check the output of `dmesg` but nothing special(related to i915 driver) was found. 
So can anyone tell me any about the i915 driver(when it will be loaded, any extra parameters to show more about it when kernel boots). Thanks a lot!

[output of dmesg](https://gist.github.com/Katsusan/8b079d5427148d41d3c3e738df2357a4)

Answer (score 0):

The `i915` driver won't be used because you have `nomodeset` on the kernel command line. Try removing that to actually start using the driver.

To get more debug output after that, try adding `drm.debug=14` module parameter. The value is a bit mask enabling various debug categories in the graphics subsystem.

Finally, if you keep having issues, try upgrading to a more recent kernel.